# RabbitMQ Operator with local path: Internal error occurred: 2 default StorageClasses were found

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, persistent-volume-claims, kubernetes-operator

I was following [rabbitmq kubernetes operator documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/quickstart-operator.html) to create rabbitmq cluster.

As instructed in documentation if pods stay long in pending state, we need to execute following 2 command to install [Local Path Provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner)

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/master/deploy/local-path-storage.yaml
kubectl annotate storageclass local-path storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
```

So now I am getting following error with local path as I have 2 storage class as default (other being "standard" provided by minikube).

```
Internal error occurred: 2 default StorageClasses were found
```

How do I fix this? Seems there is open defect for this at Kubernetes. So how do I do workaround to this issue to proceed further? I am running kubernetes in minikube.

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34549
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just delete one of the storage class.

```
 kubectl get storageclass
 # then choose the one you want to delete
 kubectl delete storageclass/<classname>
```

then restart your rabbitmq operator.

Comment: Yeah. I did that even though I didn't know implications of that. But as this was non prod environment, I had no issue doing that.